# How do I fake send SMS messages AND a system notification? Programmatical approach?

Tags: java, android, notifications, sms

Update: To state this first: I'm looking for a programmatical way. I know it is easily possible with emulators, but I'm looking for a way to have it implemented in an actual application on my phone.

I've been playing around with this for a while now, although I can write messages to the inbox or outbox with

```java
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "5551");
values.put("body", "the text of this message");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),values)
```

and of course

```java
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

The `WRITE_SMS`is there just for some of the following, because with all the things I tried I could not get the system to receive a notification. I thought about investigating the code of the built-in SMS app but could not find it.

Here come the things I tried:

```java
context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox",null);
```

has just the same non-effect like:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
byte[] b = (byte[])(SmsMessage.getSubmitPdu("5551","5552","some_text",false).encodedMessage);
Object[] vrs = {b};
intent.putExtra("pdus",vrs);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

As a workaround right now I'm calling the sms-list:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Any ideas or hints?

---

Ok, so I have been browsing the android code, especially
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/Mms/com/android/mms/transaction/MessagingNotification.java.htm

To my understanding all I'd need to do is call the public static `MessagingNotification.blockingUpdateAllNotifications(context)` after writing the SMS. Is there any way I can access this method?

Comment: Ok, so right now I'm very close to finish mimicking the built in SMS-notification. It may behave exactly the same: sounds, vibration, status-message, click-Intent. But it is a different notification. Which means that a real message puts a distinct notification. For now I actually like this behaviour. As a weak workaround it would be possible to listen to incoming messages too and delete the artificial notification as soon as a real message pops in.If anyone is interested I will put some sources online as soon as I'm finished and have cleaned up.

Comment: I tried accessing MessagingNotification.blockingUpdateAllNotifications(context) but could not do it. Also, if you have handcent or gosms notification installed, this won't instantiate those notifications. Right? Can you please upload your code somewhere as I am trying to do the same? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the "emulator control" section in DDMS to send test sms/text to your emulator. You can also enter the fake number from which the sms is to be sent.

[image]

More information can be found under in the ["Spoofing calls or SMS text messages"](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html#using-ddms) section of the Using DDMS document in the dev guide

Comment: Yes. And it is also possible to have two emulators running and send messages from one to the other by using the emulator IDs (mostly something like 555X). But that's actually not what I'm looking for. There are some apps on the market sending fake messages and being capable of notification, sometimes I like to use something like this. But due to ugly advertising in these apps I'd prefer to have my own.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question asked.